# Filter dataframe based on columns determined from user input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to get help on the creation of a program, taking in user input based on up to 2 column names and their values, and returning the respective rows within a dataframe. Should the user enter only the first column name and value, they can choose to enter 'exit' for the second column name and value inputs, to allow the program to filter only based on those.

To illustrate this example with a

## sample dataframe, df:

```
index  name  club     age   height

5      mary  band     15    160.1

6      pete  bball    16    175.2

7      john  art      11    145.5

8      cody  science  12    144.0
```

## my attempt code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("sample_data.csv")

df['age'] = df['age'].astype(str)
df['height'] = df['height'].astype(str)

first_column_name = str(input("enter first column: "))
first_column_value = str(input("enter first column value: "))

second_column_name = str(input("enter second column: "))
second_column_value = str(input("enter second column value: "))

def filter_values():
  if first_column_name == 'name' and second_column_name == 'club':
    return df[(df['name'] == first_column_value) & (df['club'] == second_column_value)]
.
.
.
filter_values()
```

## example output based on attempt code

```
enter first column: name

enter first value: mary

enter second column: club

enter second value: band
```

*dataframe output of the first row is returned, hence the coding works but is inefficient. note: actual data has more rows with varying data.*

--

In my attempt,

1. I am unsure of how to firstly, deal with the various dtypes hence I converted the
   int and float dtypes to str, as I understand user input can only take in string. Ideally, when the user inputs a str column name, the input to be taken in for the column value should only be str; and likewise for the int and float values
2. The function filter_values() which I have defined, is not the most efficient way since the actual data table I am looking at has way more columns. This would cause the code to be lengthy and I believe there should be a smarter way to take in the user input at the beginning, and to use it as the column name point-of-reference.
3. Not sure how to add in an exception where when user inputs 'exit' for the second_column_name & second_column_value, the program will just filter based on the first_column_name & first_column_value inputs.

I apologise if anything is unclear; I am a beginner and have done research over the past few days on solving this, yet am unable to find the exact answer.
Appreciate any help along my thought process on my attempt code above. TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do this

```py
df[(df[first_column_name] == first_column_value) & (df[second_column_name] == second_column_value)]
```

Do not forget to check every input column names is exists in dataframe

```py
if first_column_name not in df.columns:
    raise AttributeError(f"{first_column_name} not in dataframe columns")
```

And to exit if user do not want to filter second column then just ask him.

```py
# declare variables
second_column_name = None
second_column_value = None

add_second_filter = input("Do you want to add second filter? (Y\N): ")

if add_second_filter == 'Y':
    second_column_name = str(input("enter second column: "))
    second_column_value = str(input("enter second column value: "))

    # check that second_column_name exists in dataframe

# filter dataframe based on user input
# if add_second_filter == 'Y' filter both if not - filter only first
```

and do the same what you did with first column.

Comment: Thank you, the first code edit worked. Can I check how do I allow the the user to exit the second column filter (and only return the first filtered values based on input?